# how to write code inside javascript

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need to make a DOM substitution, something like this:

```
$("#target").html('<?php echo $html?>');
```

where the `$html` variable could be a complex markup

```
$html = '<div>
    <input type="text" name="test" />
  </div>';
```

Of course I need some kind of escaping, or the javascript engine will break for a syntax problem at the first crlf or quote. In rails there's a simple function `escape_javascript` that makes it very easy. Is there anything similar in cakephp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction)

in your view file add the below code

```
$html = $this->requestAction('/tests/func_name');

echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('
    $("#target").html('. $this->Js->value($html) .');
');
```

And in your TestsController.

```
public function func_name() {
    $this->layout = 'layout_name'; // The layout you want here for design.

    $this->render('/Elements/element_name'); // you can directly render the content of element by writing like this.
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I can't use `$this->Js` :  Undefined property View::$Js

Comment: May be you're not including the js helper. just check `$helpers` property in your controller & appcontroller and include it.

Comment: it works! I thought the JS and the Javascript helper were the same thing, but they're not.

Answer (score 1):

I think using

```
$("#target").html('<?php echo $this->element("element_path"); ?>');
```

makes more sense. But it depends on what is in your element_path.ctp file.
On the other hand, it's a bit weird to put replacement HTML in like this. Espacially if it's a lott, I would make an ajax call to load the HTML and have a Controller function return the contents of the element.

```
$("#target").html('Loading...').load('/myController/loadHtml/');
```

and the myController

```
function loadHtml(){
    $this->layout = false;
}
```

and the view for the function app/View/my/load_html.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->element("element_path"); ?>
```

Comment: The problem is the same. It returns an unescaped html

Comment: @VecchiaSpugna Why would you want to escape HTML when using the [`jQuery.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function? That doesn't make any sense. If you want the data to appear as text, then use [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead. And when there's really need to escape HTML manually, then check out [`h()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h).

Comment: because if the Jquery.html() argument is a text containing a crlf the javascript will break

Comment: @VecchiaSpugna What JavaScript? Please update your question with actual data, ie the markup of `#target` and the contents of the element.

Comment: @VecchiaSpugna Now I got you... ps in comments please use `@username` so that the one you are talking to gets notified, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @VecchiaSpugna have you tried it? I use this method to return complete pages (views) to insert into a dialogbox. It even contains another javascript block! Because the view gets rendered bij Cake your problem is solved.